# Как прочитать строки с пробелами в цикле в С++?

Tags: c++, linux

Вопрос следующий. В цикле нужно читать строки, содержащие пробелы. Признак конца строки - символ '`\n`'.  Пробовал функции `cin.getline()`, `gets()`. Результат один - читает один раз, а затем зацикливание. Вот собственно код.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Exit = 1;
    char mes[20];
    while (Exit) {
        cout << "Введите строку" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.getline(mes, 19, '\n');
        cout << "Вы ввели: " << mes << endl << "1 - продолжить\n0 - выход" << endl;
        cin >> Exit;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Создаете себе проблемы на пустом месте. Читайте просто до конца файла (без всяких красивых переменных типа Exit).

Comment: Так ведь не из файла, а из стандартного ввода читается.

Comment: А ^D (или ^Z в винде) уже не работают ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Классическая проблема. После того, как число было считано в переменную `Exit`, в буфере потока `cin` остался непрочитанный символ переноса `\n`. Он-то в последующем чтении из потока все и портит. Его можно убрать, например, так

```
cin >> Exit;
cin.ignore (7777, '\n');
```

Comment: Спасибо, выручили. А почему скажем такое же не делает функция fflush(stdin)?

Comment: Потому что она делает другое. Она сбрасывает буфер стандартного ввода в переменную, в которую читает. В этом она аналогична методу istream.synchronize()

Answer (score 1):

Также я так полагаю имелось в виду:

```
cin.getline(mes, 19, '\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

Также можно использовать:

```
cin.sync() // или
cin.ignore(cin.rdbuf()->in_avail());
cin.rdbuf()->in_avail()  //возвращает количество символов в буфере
```