# Как очистить строковый буфер с++

Tags: потоки-данных, c++

нужно считать много строк с пробелами.

Код:

```
string s;
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    getline(cin, s); //вот после этого в буфере видимо остается '\n' и дальше трэш всякий начинается

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Тыц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/89351/c-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81) и [тыц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/16019/c-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)